# What is the most efficent way to Add/Update Columns in TableA from TableB in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two Tables. Table A has 380 columns and 360 columns are created based on row value for a particular column in TABLE_B. As I add a new row to TABLE_B and if that is not the column in TABLE_A then a new column needs to be created in TABLE_A.

The columns in TABLE_A are calculated based on the logic from other column in the same table and from another table TABLE_C.

This query as below takes an hour and 30 minutes to complete.

**Is there any other optimal solution for this situation?**

I have following query but it takes about hour and half to complete.

```
Declare @@columnname varchar(25)
DECLARE column_cursor cursor for
SELECT distinct [Column For Table_A] FROM [dbo].TABLE_B
OPEN column_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor
    INTO @columnname
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
            set @starttime = GETDATE()
                if not exists (select * from sys.columns where Name = @columnname and object_id = object_ID('[TABLE_A]'))
                begin
                    SELECT @message =isnull(@columnname,'null column') +'  doesn''t exists, adding one'
                    Print @message
                    set @sqlquery  ='alter table [dbo].[TABLE_A] add ['+@columnname+'] decimal(20,5)'

                    Execute sp_executesql @sqlquery
                end
                set @sqlquery ='UPDATE [TABLE_A]
                                SET ['+@columnname+'] = [Amount]
                                where [value] = '''+@columnname+'''


                                UPDATE [TABLE_A]
                                SET  ['+@columnname+']  = (SELECT sum(total_au) totalusd from [TABLE_C] p
                                where [unique ID IC] = CONCAT([unique id],''-'','''+@columnname+''')
                                group by p.[unique ID]
                                )
                                where [value] <> '''+@columnname+'''
                                and ( ['+@columnname+'] = 0 Or ['+@columnname+'] is null)'

                Execute sp_executesql @sqlquery
            set @endtime = Getdate()
            set @elaspedtime =Datediff(second, @starttime, @endtime)
            PRINT   RIGHT('0' + CAST(@elaspedtime / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST((@elaspedtime / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(@elaspedtime % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)

        FETCH NEXT FROM 
        column_cursor
        Into @columnname
    END
Close column_cursor
DEALLOCATE column_cursor
```

Comment: If table A has 20 cols, and the query is adding 340 more cols, that is ~4 cols/min, which is 15 sec per column, correct?  Each column is doing three operations - add column, and two updates.  There is logging, I/O, scanning, etc.  If you really think it should be faster, check that your data/log files are not growing, and that I/O is not a bottleneck, and use profiler to see if your execution plans are optimal.

Comment: isn't this just a @messed-up PIVOT?

Comment: @Greg, the column is only added if that doesn't already exists. so in most of the case, there will be only two updates.

Comment: @messed-up, your initial statement detailing how many columns are in each table, is not clear, so i made an assumption.  Can you clearly tell us approx how many columns were added?  otherwise, your UPDATE statements are probably not optimal, best bet is to look at the execution plans to see why.

Comment: @Greg, updated the question a bit.

Comment: IMO, your basic approach here is deeply flawed. This is a database, not a spreadsheet. RDBMSs are designed to make adding and removing *rows* easy. The fact that you had to jump through so many hoops to get this to work should have been a clue that it's not right. You're also going to eventually hit the column limit (1024 for normal tables) or the row byte limit (8060 bytes with DECIMAL(20,5) taking 13 bytes each means 620 columns max).  If you really need a dynamic schema, I'd look at an entity-attribute-value table.